# Feedback message in LotusRB

Tags: hanami

What is the suggested way to set a feedback message in Lotus?
Something like flash messages in Rails.

In my create action I create my entity and after I redirect to index.
Now I'd like to display in index a "entity successfully saved" message.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flash` is already shipped, but not documented yet because still unstable.

To use it, please enable sessions in `apps/web/application.rb` and use it in actions/views/templates like a Hash.

Please have a look at: https://github.com/lotus/controller/blob/bb2f4b971adbff6ce4a2e050a08d4b1837bc848d/lib/lotus/action/flash.rb